# Correctly parsing json in c#

Tags: c#

I want to parse json like :

```
{
    "queryresult": {
        "success": true,
        "error": false,
        "numpods": 6,
        "datatypes": "Math",
        "timedout": "",
        "timedoutpods": "",
        "timing": 1.014,
        "parsetiming": 0.109,
        "parsetimedout": false,
        "recalculate": "",
        "id": "MSP362323b9dc107h895b64000027hfia8g5abf0bfg",
        "host": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com",
        "server": "54",
        "related": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/api/v1/relatedQueries.jsp?id=MSPa362423b9dc107h895b6400000ge80d6fecdd3g305802790122383609046",
        "version": "2.6",
        "pods": [
            {
                "title": "Input",
                "scanner": "Identity",
                "id": "Input",
                "position": 100,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP362523b9dc107h895b640000214gh7dcb3c6e027?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": "3 + 3",
                            "title": "3 + 3",
                            "width": 30,
                            "height": 18,
                            "type": "Default",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Result",
                "scanner": "Simplification",
                "id": "Result",
                "position": 200,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP362623b9dc107h895b6400005d6ad57aedd6f604?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": "6",
                            "title": "6",
                            "width": 8,
                            "height": 18,
                            "type": "Default",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "Default"
                },
                "states": [
                    {
                        "name": "Step-by-step solution",
                        "input": "Result__Step-by-step solution",
                        "stepbystep": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Number line",
                "scanner": "NumberLine",
                "id": "NumberLine",
                "position": 300,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP362723b9dc107h895b6400001971f69egfe5ac57?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": "Number line",
                            "title": "",
                            "width": 330,
                            "height": 54,
                            "type": "1DMathPlot_2",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "1DMathPlot"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Number name",
                "scanner": "Integer",
                "id": "NumberName",
                "position": 400,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP362823b9dc107h895b6400004b2i72a35885f8hf?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": "six",
                            "title": "six",
                            "width": 18,
                            "height": 18,
                            "type": "Default",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Manipulatives illustration",
                "scanner": "Arithmetic",
                "id": "Illustration",
                "position": 500,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP362923b9dc107h895b64000055i4die93dg45fa5?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": " | + | | = | \n3 | | 3 | | 6",
                            "title": " | + | | = | \n3 | | 3 | | 6",
                            "width": 130,
                            "height": 56,
                            "type": "Default",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Typical human computation times",
                "scanner": "Arithmetic",
                "id": "TypicalHumanComputationTimes",
                "position": 600,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "microsources": {
                            "microsource": "HumanComputationQuery"
                        },
                        "img": {
                            "src": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP363023b9dc107h895b6400002hcc1ibbc04h11de?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=54",
                            "alt": "age 6: 3.2 seconds | age 8: 1.8 seconds | age 10: 1.2 seconds | \nage 18: 0.83 seconds\n(ignoring concentration, repetition, variations in education, etc.)",
                            "title": "age 6: 3.2 seconds | age 8: 1.8 seconds | age 10: 1.2 seconds | \nage 18: 0.83 seconds\n(ignoring concentration, repetition, variations in education, etc.)",
                            "width": 449,
                            "height": 64,
                            "type": "Grid",
                            "themes": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
                            "colorinvertable": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "expressiontypes": {
                    "name": "Grid"
                },
                "states": [
                    {
                        "name": "More details",
                        "input": "TypicalHumanComputationTimes__More details"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sources": {
            "url": "https://www5a.myWebsite.com/sources/HumanComputationQuerySourceInformationNotes.html",
            "text": "Human computation query"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get image source from here. I use Newtonsoft.Json.My root objetct class

```
class RootObjects
{

    public class Img
    {
        public string src { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subpod
    {
        public Img img { get; set; }
    }



    public class Pod
    {
        public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Subpod> subpods { get; set; }

    }

    public class Queryresult
    {
        public System.Collections.Generic.IList<Pod> pods { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Queryresult queryresult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And i use following code for parsing json

```
var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(NotParsedResponse);
foreach (var item in dynObj.queryresult.pods)
{
    foreach (var item1 in item.subpods)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in item1.img.src)
        {      
           result += (item2).ToString();                      
        }
    }
}
```

This works but problem here is that i used many foreach loops.How can i reduce them?
It would be nice to skip them.I also tried many different ways but no luck
Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of simplifying it as per your needs by using JSONPath

```
        var objs = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader("*** YOUR JSON FILE PATH ***"))).SelectTokens("$..queryresult.pods[*].subpods[*].img")
            .Select(t => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Img>(t.ToString()));
        foreach (var rec in objs)
            Console.WriteLine(rec.src);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks for Help, but insted of path how can i paste response from http

Comment: i fix it using JObject.Parse.Thanks again